# ActiveXObject in Firefox or Chrome (not IE!)

Tags: javascript, activexobject, filesystemobject

I am trying to create an `ActiveXObject` (to use `FileSystemObject`) but it's only supported in IE.

Is there a way I can make it work in Chrome or Firefox? I need to read all the files in a specific given folder, and list those.

Well, is there another way to do it?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

ActiveX is only supported by IE - the other browsers use a plugin architecture called NPAPI. However, there's a cross-browser plugin framework called [Firebreath](http://www.firebreath.org/) that you might find useful.

Comment: Since September 2015, NPAPI support was permanently removed from Chrome ([link](https://blog.chromium.org/2014/11/the-final-countdown-for-npapi.html))

Comment: On 202002, chrome has a addon called "IE Tab" which can view the file with activexobject.

Answer (score 3):

No for the moment.

I doubt it will be possible for the future for ActiveX support will be discontinued in near future (as MS stated).

[Look here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_object.asp) about HTML Object tag, but not anything will be accepted. You should try.

Answer (score 1):

`ActiveX` is supported by Chrome.

Chrome check parameters defined in : `control panel/Internet option/Security`.

Nevertheless,if it's possible to define four different area with `IE`, `Chrome` only check "`Internet`" area.

Answer (score 1):

**ActiveX resolved in Chrome!** 
Hello all **this is not the solution but the successful workaround and I have implemented as well.** 

This required some implementation on client machine as well that why is most suitable for intranet environment and not recommended for public sites. Even though one can implement it for public sites as well the only problem is end user has to download/implement solution.

Lets understand the key problem 

**Chrome cannot communicate with ActiceX**

Solution: Since Chorme cannot communicate with ActiveX but still it can communicate with the API hosted on the client machine. So develop API using .Net MVC or any other technology so that through Ajax  call it can communicate with the API and API communicate with the ActiveX object situated on the client machine. Since API also resides in Client machine that why there is no problem in communication. This API works as mediator between Chrome browser and ActiveX.

During API implementation you might encounter CORS issues, Use JSONP to deal with it.

Pictorial view of the solution 
 [image: Pictorial view of the solution]

Other solution : Use URI Scheme like MailTo: or MS-Word to deal with outlook and word application. If your requirement is different then you can implement your customized URI Scheme.

Comment: Please do comments for additional information you require or facing difficult to understand.