# <input type="button" value="export" onclick="javascriptfunction" > doesnt call a javascript function in chrome

Tags: javascript, html

The below input is not calling JavaScript function `TableToexcel`

```
<html>

<body>


 <input type="button" value="Export to Excel" onclick="TableToExcel('tbldataresult') "/>

 <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">

                 function TableToExcel(tableid) {

                     debugger;

                var id = $('[id$="' + tableid + '"]');
                var strCopy = $('<div></div>').html(id.clone()).html();

                window.clipboardData.setData("Text", strCopy);
                var objExcel = new ActiveXObject("Excel.Application");
                objExcel.visible = false;

                var objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Add;
                var objWorksheet = objWorkbook.Worksheets(1);
                objWorksheet.Paste;
                objExcel.visible = true;


            }

            </script>



</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I'm sure it calls it but throws an error. `ActiveXObject` only exists in IE. Maybe you are interested in this question: [JavaScript: ActiveXObject in Firefox or Chrome (not IE!)](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7022568/218196). Also, you seem to be using jQuery, but you don't include it.

Comment: What's your console say?

Comment: The first thing I do with this sort of errors is to either replace the function call with an `alert()`, or put an `alert()` at the *very* beginning of the function. It's an easy test (usually) to make sure the call gets made, then you can debug from there.

Comment: It doesnt call the javascript function. @Felix Kling

Comment: @user2465036: Assuming you included jQuery, it does for me: http://jsfiddle.net/JCZ8K/. But as I said, the function makes use features that don't exist in Chrome (`window.clipboardData` doesn't seem to exist in Chrome either). I don't have experience with `ActiveXObject`, so I cannot tell you whether you can make it work in Chrome at all, but fact is that the function *does* get called.

Comment: Sorry Felix King to reply you late .It does call the fucntion ,as you said ActiveX is not supported in chrome