# What is the solution for reference error with javascript?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, firefox

I have a javascript code embedded in HTML, which copies files from one folder to another.

```
<script>
     function moveFile(test, production){
     var myObject, f;
     f = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");                                          
     f.Copyfile(test,production)
     setTimeout(function(){alert("Production image updated successfully!")},1000);                                                                            
                }
  </script>
```

When I try to run this, on IE10 I get error for permission denied. While on chrome and FF, I get error "**ReferenceError: ActiveXObject is not defined**"

How to resolve this? **Also let me know if there a better way to have feature to copy files which is compatible on all browsers.**

Comment: ActiveXobject only works in IE

Comment: Chrome and Firefox don't have Active-X.

Comment: possible duplicate of [JavaScript: ActiveXObject in Firefox or Chrome (not IE!)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7022568/javascript-activexobject-in-firefox-or-chrome-not-ie)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How to resolve this?

Check if the object exists before you try to use it.  Perhaps something like this:

```
if (typeof(window.ActiveXObject) != "undefined") {
    // your code
}
```

> Also let me know if there a better way to have feature to copy files which is compatible on all browsers.

There isn't.  Your code only works because the user has permitted a browser extension to allow it to work.  Browsers which don't have that extension, or users which don't permit it, won't work.  By default you can't control the file system from within the browser (for obvious security reasons).

Answer (score 0):

`ActiveXobject` is only available in IE

from 
[ActiveXObject in Firefox or Chrome (not IE!)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7022568/javascript-activexobject-in-firefox-or-chrome-not-ie)

> ActiveX is only supported by IE - the other browsers use a plugin
>   architecture called NPAPI. However, there's a cross-browser plugin
>   framework called Firebreath that you might find useful.