# activexobject( outlook.application ) not working in Chrome and Firefox

Tags: jquery, outlook

with ActiveX I can create an Outlook instance and start a new HTML e-Mail.

Here is the sample code:

var outlookApp = new ActiveXObject("Outlook.Application");

var nameSpace = outlookApp.getNameSpace("MAPI");

mailFolder = nameSpace.getDefaultFolder(6);

mailItem = mailFolder.Items.add('IPM.Note.FormA');

mailItem.Subject="a subject test";

mailItem.To = "an@email.here";

mailItem.HTMLBody = "**bold**";

mailItem.display (0);
Is there an equivalent for Firefox and crome. Has anyone a sample please?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

No. Only IE can work with COM objects **if** your site is trusted and can create COM objects in a script.

Comment: If my site is not trusted or trusted then how to create COM objects in a script.

Comment: You can't unless you write and convince the user to install a BHO that gives you that ability.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [mailto protocol](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa767737%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) in scripts. You can automate Outlook from IE only (refer to Dmitry's post).

Answer (score 0):

All Chrome user/ Developers know that ActiveX not supported by chrome browser due to the security reasons.

All you can do is developing workaround or resolve it using URI Scheme check my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55527700/7990050)