# How can I create a file using pure JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I Got this code to create a file using JavaScript.

```
 function WriteToFile()
        { 
            var txt = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
            var s = txt.CreateTextFile("11.txt", true);
            s.WriteLine('Hello');
            s.Close();
         }
WriteToFile();
```

it is working fine with IE but not Working in Chrome and Firefox.
usually the error is  `ReferenceError: ActiveXObject is not defined`
is there any alternate to create file in javascript, instead of `ActiveXobject(Scripting.FileSystemObject")` ?

Comment: Why not use NodeJS, you awill be able to require the File System core module and just create it using javascript as well

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ActiveXObject in Firefox or Chrome (not IE!)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7022568/activexobject-in-firefox-or-chrome-not-ie)

Comment: What do you mean by "Create file using JavaScript"? Do you want a user to download the dynamically generated file? Or how are you going to work with this file?

Comment: `is there any alternate to create file in javascript` - no, web pages can not create a file on the local filesystem, thankfully

Comment: not download.it is going to save the file @ perticular location.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't possible. At least not in pure JavaScript anyway, ActiveX objects are part of the Windows/IE thing and are NOT in the ES6 spec (http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html), which is why they're not supported in Chrome or Firefox.

If you wish to write JavaScript programs that can create files on the users local file system you're going to need to write a client side app, such as a chrome app (https://developer.chrome.com/apps/api_index) or write your program using Electron shell(http://electron.atom.io/).

However, if what you want is a cross browser solution to create files at specific locations on a user file system, it's just not really natively possible.

Sure browser plugins exist, but you'd need every user to install the plugin, so that's not exactly practical. For security reasons websites aren't allowed to read the users hard drive, and this is a good thing!