# Javascript check file in directory is readable writable or executable

Tags: javascript

I am using below code to select a directory and read each file from that directory

```
<input type="file"onchange="checkFiles(this.files)" webkitdirectory directory multiple>
```

In below code I am able to read each files in directory and it properties like name, size and type.
But did not found any way to check if files are readable, writable  or executable.

```
function checkFiles(files) {
    for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
        //check for readable writable or executable files
    }
}
```

Comment: Nope.  Here is the File object: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File

Comment: readable/writable/executable are filesystem and OS permissions, not properties of the file itself.

Answer (score 0):

If writeable = not read-only then maybe you can try to use [this](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/JavaScript/0600__MS-JScript/FileAttributes.htm) example.
As Dan-o mentioned, this will only work for internet explorer.
For other browsers compatibility, try to dig in into 
[activex object in firefox or chrome not ie](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7022568/activexobject-in-firefox-or-chrome-not-ie).

```
function get() {
    var myObject, f;
    myObject = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
    f = myObject.GetFile("c:\\test.txt");

    if(!f.attributes) {
        //No attributes set
    }
    else {

        if (f.attributes & 1) {
            //Read only
        }

        else if (f.attributes & 2) {
            //Hidden
        }

        else if (f.attributes & 4) 
            //System
        }

        else if (f.attributes & 8) { 
            //Volume label
        }

        else if (f.attributes & 16) {
            //Folder
        }

        else if (f.attributes & 32) {
            //Archive bit set
        }

        if (f.attributes & 64) {
            //Shortcut or link
        }

        if (f.attributes & 128) {
            //File is compressed
        }
    }
```

You can combine this with gettnig the MIME type of a file.

Comment: you should probably mention that it's IE-only.