# can anyone tell me any alternative of activexobject for firefox and chrome for sending email using microsoft outlook?

Tags: javascript

i'm having a problem in sending emails using javascript in chrome and firefox.
As we know activexobject only works in internet explorer so there must be an alternate to send emails with large body content for chrome and firefox

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ActiveXObject in Firefox or Chrome (not IE!)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7022568/activexobject-in-firefox-or-chrome-not-ie)

Answer (score 1):

A bit "low-tech", but you could leverage the mailto protocol:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa767737(v=vs.85).aspx

`window.open('mailto:user@example.com?subject=Message Title&body=Message Content');`

Comment: mailto does not support large content for body attribute

Comment: I want to send large amount of body content and mailto does not support it is there any option to send attachment in mailto?