# How to write into a file (.txt or .html) in javascript

Tags: javascript

does anyone know how to write into a file (.txt or .html) in javscript.
I got multiple answers in google but none of them are working.
Currently I am using this line :

```
var FileOpener = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");;
var FilePointer = FileOpener.OpenTextFile("C:\Users\sidkr\Desktop\sid.txt", 8, true);
FilePointer.WriteLine("I m a good boy");
FilePointer.Close();
```

But getting following error
ActiveXObject is not defined

I am using google chrome for development

Comment: ActiveX is an Internet Explorer feature only. So it won't work in Chrome

Comment: if you are using any other browser then `IE` it will through that error refer to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7172981/2417602) for more info.

Comment: This object is a Microsoft extension and is supported in Internet Explorer only, not in Windows 8.x Store apps. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/scripting/javascript/reference/activexobject-object-javascript

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to read and write into file using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/585234/how-to-read-and-write-into-file-using-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

From the microsoft docs

> This object is a Microsoft extension and is supported in Internet
>   Explorer only, not in Windows 8.x Store apps.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/scripting/javascript/reference/activexobject-object-javascript

Take a look at this question here
[Is it possible to write data to file using only JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21012580/is-it-possible-to-write-data-to-file-using-only-javascript)