# How to run bat file from HTML Page on button click using javascript in latest Chrome/Firefox?

Tags: javascript, html, batch-file

I want to execute a batch file on a button click event from simple HTML page.

In IE, I can use `ActiveXObject` to achieve this however in other browser `ActiveXObject` is not supported.

Sample HTML File:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Run Batch</title>
<HTA:APPLICATION
  APPLICATIONNAME="Run Batch"
  ID="MyHTMLapplication"
  VERSION="1.0"/>
</head>
<script type="text/javascript">

function RunBat(){

    var shell = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
    var path = "D:/Test.bat";
    shell.run(path);
}
</script>

</head>
<form>
Execute:
<input type="button" Value="Run" onClick="RunBat();"/>
</form>
</html>
```

I have gone through many questions on different forums and what I have found is that, in other browsers it is possible through some add-ons.

Is there any other way to execute it without using any add-ons in other browser?

If no, what are the add-ons I can use for Firefox, Chrome and Edge browsers to achieve this?

Comment: What does the batch script actually do? It might be a case that there is a better way to trigger it from all browsers if you can share that.

Comment: I understand you want it code in JavaScript, but don't you want it to code in PHP?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ActiveXObject in Firefox or Chrome (not IE!)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7022568/activexobject-in-firefox-or-chrome-not-ie)

Comment: @DarrenSweeney - The batch script executes a set of java command. It compiles a java file and then run the class file.

Answer (score 1):

Due to security reasons it's not possible to launch user files (as batch scripts) from the web browser. This is unless you're trying to develope an electron app, which i think you could see, in that case try this code:
(REQUIRES NODE.JS INTEGRATION)

```
"use strict";
var myBatFilePath = "C:\\Path\\To\\User\\s\\file.bat";
const spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
var bat = spawn('cmd.exe', ['/c', myBatFilePath]);

bat.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
    //Logs the batch's echos to the console
    var str = String.fromCharCode.apply(null, data);
    console.info(str);
});

bat.stderr.on('data', (data) => {
    //Logs as error the batch's echos that end with "1>&2"
    var str = String.fromCharCode.apply(null, data);
    console.error(str);
});

bat.on('exit', (code) => {
    //Handles batch exit codes
    var preText = `Child exited with code ${code} : `;
    switch(code){
        case 0:
            console.info(preText); // EXIT CODE 0 (no exit code provided)
            break;
        case 1:
            console.info(preText); // EXIT CODE 1
            break;
        case 2:
            console.info(preText); // EXIT CODE 2
            break;
        case 3:
            console.info(preText); // EXIT CODE 3
            break;
        //AND SO ON
    }
});
```